# Strange behavior in Angular form validation

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation, angularjs-digest

I am using an Angular directive to validate a form through a regex. A minimal representation of the code and HTML is given below.

**The issue:**
The weird behavior is the following: the form signals an error with inputs of even length but not with inputs of odd length. Example keystrokes:

> a --> valid
>
> aa --> invalid
>
> aaa --> valid
>
> aaaa --> invalid

This happens both when typing and deleting letters.
However, if I past aaaa or any string of even length it shows no error.
I doubt it might be due to Angular digest loop, but I cannot figure out the issue.

Any clues on what I might want to look at?

**Code**

This is my directive:

```
var valid_input_regex = /^[\w]+$/g;

directives.directive('pn', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.pn = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            if (!valid_input_regex.test(modelValue)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
    }
};
});
```

And in the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" pn>
<span ng-show="(form.name.$error.pn && !form.name.$pristine)">Please use plain text or numbers.</span>
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your problem, but your return statement is very inefficient. `if (!valid_input_regex.test(modelValue)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;` is the same as `return valid_input_regex.test(modelValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of the 'g' at the end of your regex

```
var valid_input_regex = /^[\w]+$/;
```

Should work then